# Domain transfered to OVH but DNS Host is still on 1and1

Tags: dns, transfer

I've transfered a domain from 1and1.com to OVH, now I need to manage my DNS to point them to a new server, but running this command from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38021/how-do-i-find-the-authoritative-name-server-for-a-domain-name)

```
command line> nslookup
> set querytype=soa
> mydomain.com
```

I found out that DNS are still managed from 1and1.

Reading the [OVH guide](http://www.ovh.it/item/zona_dns.xml) about DNS i found out that i need to activate DNS zone from my manager. But... won't this conflict with the DNS declared on 1and1?

I'm not sure about how is this working, so does someone knows the right workflow to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

after a call with OVH Support the correct workflow is:

- Create or configure the DNS zone
- Change the DNS Server to the OVH server

in 24 hours all should work fine, I'll let you know...