# Point Domain to Adobe Business Catalyst Hosting using DNS Records

Tags: dns, business-catalyst

I have a site for which I adjusted the NS records 1-3 to point to Adobe Business Catalyst where the site is hosted now:

```
domain.nl.  ns1.worldsecuresystems.com.
domain.nl.  ns2.worldsecuresystems.com.
domain.nl.  ns3.worldsecuresystems.com.
```

I assumed this would be enough to point to the new server with site data. When I did a dig I saw

```
dig +short SOA domain.nl
ns1.worldsecuresystems.com. hostmaster.domain.nl. 2014071224 14400 3600 1209600 86400
```

When I checked the site on [viewdns.info](http://viewdns.info) I got two warnings though:

```
Oops! Your local nameservers don't return IP addresses (glue) along with your NS records! This isn't a fatal error but means an extra lookup needs to be performed increasing the load time to your site. You can fix this by adding A records for each of the nameservers listed above.
```

and

```
Oops! It appears that the following nameserves listed at your local servers are not listed at the parent servers:

    ns1.worldsecuresystems.com. 
    ns2.worldsecuresystems.com. 
    ns3.worldsecuresystems.com. 

    You should ensure that these nameservers are valid and working. If they are not, you will encounter connectivity issues with your domain.
```

And the site is not resolving properly. It is still going to the old hoster's ip (hosted with [correcthosting.nl](http://correcthosting.nl) ) where the old site is now.

```
nslookup domain.nl
Server:     x.x.x.x
Address:    x.x.x.x#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   domain.nl
Address: XXX.xx.xx.xx // old ip address
```

I do not see a reason why it does not work. I have asked Business Catalyst and the hoster where the domain is at for help a while ago, but will have to wait for answers. If anyone here in the meanwhile has some pointers that would be great.

Comment: I do have a pointer after the domain name and at the end of the domain name server. Something I now understand after having read http://www.dns-sd.org/TrailingDotsInDomainNames.html . Also read http://www.site-helper.com/dns.html . Does not help me debugging the issue. Could be that there is an issue at Adobe's side. Waiting for a reply to my ticket opened. Cannot seem to look at DNS records there now. It has been about 24 hours now. Perhaps the issue is: that the host hasn't removed my domain record from their name servers or I still have to wait another 24 hours.

Comment: Did a propagation check at https://www.whatsmydns.net/ on A record. Did not know this site before. Seems several locations do load the correct ip address instead of the old one, but not the ones in Holland. So the issue is a propagation issue.

Comment: Also found http://helpx.adobe.com/business-catalyst/kb/domain-name-dns---quick.html now which is useful in explaining the need for additional A Records.

Comment: Additionally it should be mentioned a general A record pointing to the ip of the new location of site files was needed. On NS issues see great answers below by @Bushmills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your domain is domain.nl, you don't need glue for nameservers ns*.worldsecuresystems.com. Whoever says that you need glue in this situation, is lying to you, unless you are lying about your domain name. 
DNS doesn't *propagate* - records *expire*. Use dig or drill for querying nameserver.

> "It appears that the following nameserves listed at your local servers are not listed at the parent servers"

this message is an indication of neglect or failure to delegate authority to the nameservers specified with NS records in your zone. This may be related to the problem with glue records missing, but doesn't explain why glue is considered needed.

the data in SOA record says nothing about authority over zone. delegation records in parent zone do.
Seeing that you're using dig already, try   dig +trace yourdomain to see delegation chain.

> "site is not resolving properly. It is still going to the old hoster"

means it's resolving properly, just not to the ip address you were expecting.

However, ns1.worldsecuresystems.com doesn't consider itself authoritative for domain.nl, which is a sign that the zone domain.nl hasn't been set up on that nameserver.

Comment: The hoster of the domain correcthosting.nl told me ns1 and ns2 should be theirs and that the third ns3 should be `ns3.worldsecuresystems.com.` . I am only now trying to figure out if these first two should be `ns1.pro-dns.nl.` and `ns2.pro-dns.nl.`. as the parent server was showing now when I did a query on viewdns.info . As I also never did a setup like this before I asked them why this is the case. They might not reply until Monday though.

Comment: authoritative for correcthosting.nl are ns1.correcthosting-admin.nl and ns2.correcthosting-admin.nl. A domain hoster will ask to use their nameservers - providing name servers for DNS services is all a domain hoster does, without using their nameservers you don't need that domain hoster.  "registrar" is different from "domain hoster" which again is different from, say, "web hoster" even though same company may offer all those services.

Comment: How did you find the authoritative name server for correct hosting.nl ? Did you use nslookup as used here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38021/how-do-i-find-the-authoritative-name-server-for-a-domain-name ?

Comment: dig correcthosting.nl NS - I don't use nslookup as it's results are much harder to interpret correctly than dig output is.

Comment: Hoster mentioned I should use `ns1.pro-dns.nl.` as the parent server uses. Not sure how I can find the parent dns server as viewdns.info did using Dig myself. Been reading on parent local server mismatch some more and will so some more research.

Comment: i don't understand "parent dns server". I do understand "parent zone" - if they mean "use the nameservers as specified (by NS records) in parent zone", those are the nameservers which are authoritative for your domain, because authority delegated to those. you can change that, though, and are not required to use any specific nameserver only because it was suggested to you. It is your domain, you determine what your authoritative nameserver are going to be. Important is that NS records in parent zone match  NS record in your domain - and that they resolve and can be resolved, evidently.